# How can I print from this object? Java

Tags: java, object

I need to print the first name, last name, and salary from two employee objects but I keep getting a cannot find symbol error.  What would I do to fix this?

Here is the constructor class:

```
public class Employee
    {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private double monthlySalary;

        public Employee( String firstName1, String lastName1, double monthlySalary1) {
            setfirstName(firstName1);
            setlastName(lastName1);
            setmonthlySalary(monthlySalary1);
        }

        String getfirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        String getlastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        double getmonthlySalary() {
            return monthlySalary;
        }

        public void setfirstName (String firstName1) {
            firstName = firstName1;
        }

        public void setlastName (String lastName1) {
            lastName = lastName1;
        }

        public void setmonthlySalary (double monthlySalary1) {
            monthlySalary = ( monthlySalary1 >= 0 ? monthlySalary1 : 0);
        }
    }
```

And here is what I have so far to print the objects:

```
public class EmployeeTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Employee a = new Employee("John", "Smith", 10000);
            Employee b = new Employee("Jane", "Smith", 11000);
            System.out.print(a.firstName1);
         }
   }
```

I need to be able to have it print out something along the lines of "Name: Salary:" But I am clueless as to how to make this work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is not field ``firstName1`` in your Employee class.

Comment: Override the `toString()` method inherited by all Java classes or use the (should be public) getters to create your own output.

Comment: you have to make a visible accessor for EmployeeTest as you did with your mutator setter, make a getter!

Answer (score 1):

In your employee class, you need to override the toString() method.

You can try something like:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
   System.out.println("Name: "+name+"Salary: "+salary);
}
```

Then for each of your employees, when you want to print them, just call

```
System.out.println(employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant print out `firstName` (or `firstName1`, because that doesnt exist in your class), because its marked as private. You should do something like this:

```
System.out.print(a.getfirstName())
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstName` is `private`, which means that it cannot be seen outside of the object/class it resides in. I suggest you try overriding the `toString()` method on your `Employee` class. That method would have access to all the private members of `Employee`.

Alternately, you could use `getfirstName()` to return the first name.

Also, this may be a typo, but there is no `firstName1` in Employee - it is `firstName`.